# Display Alias name for each column in dynamic query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have below table.

```
create table demo(id int, dataval varchar(50))

insert into demo 
    select 1, 'val'
    union
    select 2, 'val1'
    union
    select 3, 'val3'
```

I am trying to get the list of values of dataval column surrounded with `max()` in a variable using below query

```
DECLARE @maxcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @maxcols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + 'MAX('+QUOTENAME([dataval] ) + ') AS [val]' 
                         FROM demo
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @maxcols AS val
```

I am getting below values.

```
max([val])as [val],max([val1])as [val],max([val3])as [val]
```

Here the alias name coming as static value [val]. I need the alias name displayed as column values.

Expected output:

```
max([val])as [val1],max([val1])as [val2],max([val3])as [val3]
```

Could someone help on this?

Comment: What's the logic behind wanting `max([val])as [val1],max([val1])as [val2]`?    It doesn't fit what you seem to be asking for with "I need the alias name displayed as column values."    And why can't you use the same dynamic technique for your aliases that you used for your columns?

Comment: I tried to make the alias values as dynamic. But I am getting error..

Comment: Post your attempt to make them dynamic and the error you got.

Answer (score 3):

You can use row_Number as below:

```
DECLARE 
     @maxcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @maxcols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + 'max('+QUOTENAME([dataval] )+')as [val'+ convert(varchar(10), Row_Number() over (order by (SELECT NULL))) + ']' 
                    from  demo
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @maxcols as val
```

Output as below:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              val                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| max([val])as [val1],max([val1])as [val2],max([val3])as [val3] |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question that was asked, but I'm 99% sure this won't solve the OP's actual problem.

Comment: thanks. But the  i put val1, val2 for demonstration purpose. the actual table is having around 100 + with varchar values in dataval column

Comment: @bmsqldev not able to understand your question... You can use Concat that will automatically convert to required varchar datatype

Comment: in the actual table the columns are not suffixed numbers.

Comment: sorry I think your answer will sequentially assign numbers to each column.  But the expected output is different. for instance, there are values in the dataval column like "usa", "india", "Uk"  etc..how will handle those?

Comment: Can you provide appropriate sample data?